# What's the main difference between match and if-let in rust?

Tags: rust

I get little confused when learning about control flow. I don't understand the difference between `if-let` and `match`.

```rust
fn main() {
    let some_u8_value = Some(8u8);
    // println!(" {} ", some_u8_value);
    if let Some(value) = some_u8_value {
        println!(" {} ", value);
    } else {
        println!("not a num");
    }

    match some_u8_value {
        Some(value) => println!(" {} ", value),
        None => println!("not a num"),
    }
}
```

Why do we need `if-let`?

Comment: Match can check more conditions and must be exhaustive. In your example with `Option`, (and many other like with `Result`) there isn't much difference between them.

Comment: The same difference as between `if` and `switch` in some other languages. `if` is shorter when checking 1-2 values, `switch` is shorter when checking 3 and more values

Comment: [Section 6.3](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch06-03-if-let.html#concise-control-flow-with-if-let) from the book already explains this pretty well: _"The if let syntax lets you combine if and let into a less verbose way to handle values that match one pattern while ignoring the rest. [...] Using if let means less typing, less indentation, and less boilerplate code. [...] Choosing between match and if let depends on what you’re doing in your particular situation and whether gaining conciseness is an appropriate trade-off for losing exhaustive checking."_

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Why do we need if-let?

We don't *need* it, it's a convenience feature. Per [RFC 160](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/0160-if-let.html) which introduced it:

> [`if let`] allows for refutable pattern matching without the syntactic and semantic overhead of a full match, and without the corresponding extra rightward drift.

and

> The idiomatic solution today for testing and unwrapping an Option looks like
>
> ```rust
> match optVal {
>     Some(x) => {
>         doSomethingWith(x);
>     }
>     None => {}
> }
> ```
>
> This is unnecessarily verbose, with the `None => {}` (or `_ => {}`) case being required, and introduces unnecessary rightward drift (this introduces two levels of indentation where a normal conditional would introduce one).
>
> [explanation of the issues with using a simple `if` with `is_some` and `unwrap`]
>
> The if let construct solves all of these problems, and looks like this:
>
> ```rust
> if let Some(x) = optVal {
>     doSomethingWith(x);
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, my friend.  Your answer solved my great trouble and I believe it will also help many novices like me. Have a good day

Comment: What percentage of Rust programmers use if-let?  As a noob, I am thinking of just using `match` statements.

Comment: Couldn't tell you. Using `if let` is certainly not a requirement, it's mostly useful for edge cases or for working with `Option` (as you never need a second branch). Checking the projects I have a clone of, `rustc` itself seems to use `if let` at about half the rate it uses `match`, while `ripgrep` is 1/10th. It's going to depend on the coding style and subject matter.

Comment: using if let allows you to not handle the Err. IMO, a match should be preferred. if let should only be used in prototypes.

Comment: That is complete nonsense. First, `if let` is not specific to `Result` so that's not a valid objection, second even with `Result` there are lots of cases where you only care about success / failure (not about the specifics of the failure), or even success alone, and `if let` is sufficient and convenient for that, when HOFs combinators are not suitable.